# git push origin master shows eveything up-to-date but nothing is pushed

Tags: bitbucket

When I build new text file in bitbucket and pull it to my local file, it works. But when I build new text file in local and push it ot bitbucket with git push origin master,it shows everything up-to-date but nothing is pushed in bitbucket.

Comment: Bold text for nothing -> downvote.

Comment: did you make changes? If yes then you need to locally commit it and then push it to git

Comment: I did not make any changes.Here are my steps.Please check.

Comment: mkdir repos
cd ~/repos
clone this repository and past and enter
cd ~/repos/tutorial
echo"Earth" >> location.txt
git add location.txt
git push origin master

Comment: i did not make any changes.just create a file and push it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use these commands sequentially

1) git add --all

2) git commit -m "message"

3) git pull origin master

4) git push origin master